# Can not update NSUserDefaults NSMutableDictionary Object

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nsmutablearray, nsuserdefaults, nsmutabledictionary

I'm trying to Update a Dictionary, saved in the UserDefaults.

However, it just doesn't want to update the Object at the given Index. I have no idea why. The Object with it's values stay the same.

Code:

```
- (void) saveUser
{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSMutableArray *users = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"users"]];

    BOOL userAlreadyAdded = FALSE;
    NSUInteger count = 0;

    for (NSMutableDictionary *user in users) {

        if ([[user objectForKey:@"username"] isEqualToString:[defaults objectForKey:@"username"]]) {

            NSLog(@"User found: %@", user);

            [user setObject:sid forKey:@"sess"];
            [user setObject:mid forKey:@"seca"];
            [users replaceObjectAtIndex:count withObject:user];

            userAlreadyAdded = TRUE;

        }

        count++;

    }

    if (!userAlreadyAdded) {

        NSMutableDictionary *userToAdd = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
            [defaults objectForKey:@"username"], @"username",
            sid, @"sess",
            mid, @"seca",
            nil];

        [users addObject:userToAdd];

    }

    NSLog(@"USERS TO SAVE: %@", users);

    [defaults setObject:users forKey:@"users"];

    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Values returned from NSUserDefaults are immutable, even if you set a
>   mutable object as the value. For example, if you set a mutable string
>   as the value for "MyStringDefault", the string you later retrieve
>   using stringForKey: will be immutable.

try removing the object and adding it again.

Comment: thanks...now it works. I also tried it with mutableCopy and that changed nothing, so I was wondering why. now it works!

Answer (score 0):

For each user create a Mutable Dictionary from the one you have like you already did with 'users' (initWithArray).

NSMutableDictionary* mutableUser = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:user];

Also I'm not entirely sure you're safe to presume that the object at index of your count is the object you expect because the for in loop enumerates differently. I would use setObjectForKey, not replaceAtIndex.